# Segmentation fault SIGSEGV when dereferencing a node

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes, doubly-linked-list, dereference

I am not sure if the way I have approached this is more complicated than it has to be. Please recommend a better alternative if you have an idea. I am trying to create a series of nodes (windows) that each contain a string of alternate nodes (the visual information in the box struct).

Here is the line highlighted by my debugger:

```
temp->obj_tail->next = n;

// temp is a node, and temp->obj_tail dereferences a node of the same struct
```

I am getting the response: "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."

I have head, tail, and temp initialized to NULL with this constructor

```
cmenu::cmenu():
    head(NULL),
    tail(NULL),
    temp(NULL)
{
}
```

Code within the main that calls the class function

```
cmenu Menu;

Menu.addWindow("side_bar");
Menu.addWindow("home");
Menu.addWindow("help");

//Box structs defined here, code omitted.

Menu.addBox("side_bar", "box_1", box1);
Menu.addBox("home", "box_2", box2);
Menu.addBox("help", "box_3", box3);
```

Corresponding structures in the .h

```
struct box
{
    int x; int y; int z;
    int w; int h;
    int fill_color; int fill_char;
    int text_color; std::string text;
    bool enabled;

box():
    x(0),y(0),z(0),
    w(0), h(0),
    fill_color(8), fill_char(32), enabled(true),
    text_color(15), text(""){}
};


class cmenu
{
    private:

        typedef struct node
        {
            node* next;       // Next node
            node* prev;       // Prev node
            node* obj_head;   // Head of other node stack
            node* obj_tail;   // Tail of other node stack
            bool enabled;     // Allows toggle of element
            std::string id;   // Used to ID nodes
            box box;          // Visual element

        } *nodePtr;

        nodePtr head;
        nodePtr tail;
        nodePtr temp;


// class functions here, code omitted.

};
```

Function in the class .cpp where the error occurs

```
void cmenu::addBox(std::string win_id, std::string box_id, box b)
{
    temp = head;
    while (temp->id != win_id) {
        if (temp != tail) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    // At this point the program has found the node with the id of
    // win_id. And now my goal is to connect a new and separate 
    // string of nodes to the obj_head and obj_tail.
    // This can only happen if there has already been a node connected
    // which is what the else statement does when temp->obj_tail is NULL
    // so this shouldn't be happening

    if (temp->id == win_id) {

        nodePtr n = new node;

        n->id = box_id; // The id is assigned
        n->box = b;     // The box struct is set/copied to the passed parameter

        // obj_tail is NULL when no nodes are connected to the obj_head/obj_tail
        if (temp->obj_tail != NULL) {
            temp->obj_tail->next = n;
            n->prev = temp->obj_tail;
            n->next = NULL;
            temp->obj_tail = n;
        }
        else {
            n->next = NULL;
            n->prev = NULL;
            // This is where obj_head and obj_tail are assigned and cannot be NULL.
            temp->obj_head = n; 
            temp->obj_tail = n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to check that `temp` is not a null pointer anywhere? When the debugger stops, what is the value of `temp` and `temp->obj_tail`? Do they look valid? Have you tried stepping through the code line by line to see when and where it goes wrong? Do you remember to set all pointers to null initially? And why do you have `temp` as a member variable instead of a local variable in the function?

Comment: I have temp defined in the private area of my class. I don't know what the most efficient or correct way of doing so is but I don't think that's my issue. I just added information about my constructor. It should be NULL. How would I go about checking if the pointer is NULL? I do check using: temp->obj_tail != NULL, but cannot dereference next without an error.

Comment: It seems your temp->obj_tail is really not NULL (eg. uninitialized) and it contains some random dangerous value, where dereferencing it causes your trouble. It would be useful to see how you fill in your linked list prior to calling addBox() method (in addWindow() method??).